# How to send a simple mail using mailchimp in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, email, sendmail, mailchimp

I have tried this code

```
$listId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';

//Mailchimp instantiation with Key

$mailchimp = new \Mailchimp('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxx');

$mailchimp->from('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$mailchimp->reply_to('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
$mailchimp->to($email->email);
$mailchimp->subject('x');xxxxxxxxxxxxx
$mailchimp->message('<html>hiiiii</html');
$mailchimp->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html');
$mailchimp->send();
```

Comment: ... and? What happened? Some errors?  There are many results here on SO for "Mailchimp Laravel", have you checked them?

Answer (score 2):

Mailchimp
Installation

```
composer require nztim/mailchimp
```

For Laravel support:
Laravel 5.5+ will auto-discover the package, for earlier versions you will need to:
Add the service provider to `config/app.php:` NZTim\Mailchimp\MailchimpServiceProvider::class,
Register the facade: `'Mailchimp' => NZTim\Mailchimp\MailchimpFacade::class,`
Add an .env value for MC_KEY (your API key)
Optionally, publish the config file:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider=NZTim\Mailchimp\MailchimpServiceProvider
```

Code Email: -

```
$member = (new NZTim\Mailchimp\Member($email))->merge_fields(['FNAME' => 'First name'])->email_type('text')->confirm(false);
Mailchimp::addUpdateMember($member);
```

Examples

```
// Laravel:
// Subscribe a user to your list, existing subscribers will not receive confirmation emails
Mailchimp::subscribe('listid', 'user@domain.com');

// Subscribe a user to your list with merge fields and double-opt-in confirmation disabled
Mailchimp::subscribe('listid', 'user@domain.com', ['FNAME' => 'First name', 'LNAME' => 'Last name'], false);

// Subscribe/update a user using the Member class
$member = (new NZTim\Mailchimp\Member($email))->interests(['abc123fed' => true])->language('th');
Mailchimp::addUpdateMember('listid', $member);
```

Errors

1. Exceptions are thrown for all errors.
2. Networking/communications errors will usually be of the type Requests_Exception.
3. API errors will be of the base type NZTim\Mailchimp\MailchimpException, e.g. incorrect API key, list does not exist.
4. NZTim\Mailchimp\Exception\MailchimpBadRequestException includes a response() method that returns the response body as an array.
5. Gotchas: the API throws an error when you:

   *Specify a merge field name with incorrect capitalisation

   *Omit a required merge field when adding a new member

Comment: Hey, I am not getting idea, can you please understand me one by one?

Comment: you just copied the readme file of the package. nothing new...